# Azure Devops Release pipeline(s) for multiple Azure Functions

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a solution containing 3 projects: 2 Azure Functions and a shared library.
I have created 2 Function Apps in Azure.

My Build Pipeline is triggered every time something changes in the solution.

Now, trying to set my release pipeline

[image]

I can see I can choose the target App Service, but I can't seem to find a way to tell which function to deploy there.
It seems by default, it deploys both of them, and the first one deployed is just overwritten by the second one.
So I don't mind doing 2 release pipelines, but how do I specify : "deploy this proj from the solution".

EDIT1:
I didnt put the yaml files directly in the solution, I just added the steps in the build :
[image]

But in the release pipeline I dont see the zip file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Function is built into a zip, which can be saved into an artifact during function building. You should have an azure-pipelines.yaml in each fuction project. There you can specify the [artifact details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops), normally after restore and build steps, and zipping the build output:

```
    // restore step ...
    // build step ...
    
// now .net publishing step with zipping. You can also set this to false and use ArchiveFiles@2 step instead
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'MyFunction: Publish'
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
        projects: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyFunction/MyFunction.sln'
        publishWebProjects: false
        zipAfterPublish: True

// Now publish your zip as artifact
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'MyFunction: Publish Artifact MyFunction.zip'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.......'
        ArtifactName: 'MyFuction-Deploy'
```

Or in editor:
[image]

Than in your release pipeline click on the 3 dots near the "Package or folder" option. You should see a folder for linked artifacts, inside your build subfolder and than the artifact with your function app zip inside.

You can produce several artifacts for different function apps in your unified build pipeline, and than choose appropriate artifact to deploy in your different release pipelines.

Comment: Hello, the link you provided is marked as obsolete by Microsoft. I'm gonna look into this and let you know if I managed to make it work, thank you.

Comment: You can replace it with this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops This is replacement.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh apparently something is wrong, I cannot see the zip file ..

Comment: What do you see in the build pipeline output in the publish step? Was the artifact uploaded? Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 1 files
File upload succeed.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh, in the publish pipeline output is : Uploaded 729,844 out of 730,853 bytes
Content upload is done!
I dont see any zip creation actually

Comment: You have to create it in your build pipeline (updated the answer)